# Schanuel's conjecture and abstract elementary classes

Tags: nt.number-theory, model-theory

Are there any connections between Schanuel's conjecture and abstract elementary classes. More precisely

**Question.** Is there any conjecture in abstract elementary classes whose truth implies the Schanuel's conjecture?

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but in case you are still interested the work of Zilber is the most relevant to your question. I  am copying and pasting from Rami Grossberg's "Classification Theory for AECs".

Let $K_{\exp}$ consist of all triples of the form $\langle F, +, \cdot, \exp \rangle$ that satisfy the following:

1. $F$ is an algebraically closed field of  characteristic zero
2. $\forall x\forall y [\exp(x + y) = \exp(x) \cdot \exp(y)]$
3. $\mathop{\rm ker}(\exp)=2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$
4. the class is existentially closed
5. the class has the countable closure property, i.e. every analytic subset of $F^n$ of dimension $0$ is essentially countable, and
6. the class satisfies Schanuel's Conjecture.

Then Zilber proved that $K_{\exp}$ is $\aleph_1$-categorical and excellent. By results of Shelah $K_{\exp}$ has arbitrarily large models and it is categorical in every uncountable cardinality. This implies that $K_{\exp}$ has a unique model of size $2^{\aleph_0}$. So, Zilber concluded that in order to prove Schanuel's conjecture it suffices to prove that the function $\exp(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ is indeed $e^x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, you are right. I will edit.